# Why do we have to unmount a USB and format it to FAT or NTFS partition before making a liveUSB?

Tags: mount, live-usb, unmount

I am not able to figure out why do we have to unmount a USB and format it to *FAT* or *NTFS* partition before we can make a *liveUSB*. I have seen that when I use a `dd` command to make a *liveUSB* with a mounted USB, the data gets corrupted, why is it that?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple questions, let me answer them separately.

Let me make a distinction between a device (located in /dev) and a mounted filesystem. Think of the device as an interface to the hardware, and the filesystem as the method to write and keep track of the data on the device. In order to write data directly to the device, it must not be in use, and by extension, mounted. A device and a mounted filesystem are different, and cannot be treated the same.

The reason why you must use FAT32 is because it is a universally recognized filysystem,  bootable, and the standard catch-all that motherboard manufacturers use to start the boot process.

When you are trying to dd an image to a filesystem, you are trying to write raw data to a mounted filesystem without actually writing using the filesystem, which overwrites superblocks and makes each block not consistent with what data is actually present, corrupting any data that you had there.

## A metaphor:

Think of a filing cabinet (storage device) that has a very important method of organization (superblocks and metadata), and the normal way to add, read, or remove information from that cabinet is to ask the secretary (filesystem) to do what you want her to, since she's the only one who knows how to organize the files so that they can be easily recovered. If you go and try to put information into the cabinet directly without using the secretary, then her record of what files are present and where they are is no longer correct, and she will be unable to keep track of what is in the cabinet, making the information sometimes irretrievable.